# System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory - weirdest exception ever

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, system.io.directory

so, I'm trying to create a following directory:

> d:\temp\ak\ty\nul

Path is constructed in the loop, starting from: *d:\temp* and so on, creating non-existent directories along the way, so it first creates:

> d:\temp\ak

then:

> d:\temp\ak\ty

and.... then it comes to the last bit *nul* it throws this exception:

[image]

So, what's going on - where it took *\.\nul* from?

The code:

```
string z_base_path = @"d:\temp\ak\ty";
string z_extra_path = "nul";
string z_full_path = System.IO.Path.Combine(z_base_path, z_extra_path);

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(z_full_path);
```

Comment: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows, `nul` is a reserved file name. No file or directory may be named that. Other reserved names include:

- `con`
- `prn`
- `aux`
- `com{0-9}`
- `lpt{0-9}`

Answer (score 2):

'nul' is a device file meaning that no file/folder can have that name.
instead of

```cs
string z_extra_path = "nul";
```

try

```cs
string z_extra_path = "null";
```

or

```cs
string z_extra_path = "";
```

other ones are

- `con`
- `aux`
- `com1-9`
- `lpt1-9`
- `prn`

Answer (score 0):

Never knew this one until I came against it - it's worth nothing the Windows Directory reserved names and all the rest.

Taken from about article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

**Folder Naming Conventions**

The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file system:

Use a period to separate the base file name from the extension in the name of a directory or file.

Use a backslash () to separate the components of a path. The backslash divides the file name from the path to it, and one directory name from another directory name in a path. You cannot use a backslash in the name for the actual file or directory because it is a reserved character that separates the names into components.

Use a backslash as required as part of volume names, for example, the "C:" in "C:\path\file" or the "\server\share" in "\server\share\path\file" for Universal Naming Convention (UNC) names. For more information about UNC names, see the Maximum Path Length Limitation section.

Do not assume case sensitivity. For example, consider the names OSCAR, Oscar, and oscar to be the same, even though some file systems (such as a POSIX-compliant file system) may consider them as different. Note that NTFS supports POSIX semantics for case sensitivity but this is not the default behavior. For more information, see CreateFile.

Volume designators (drive letters) are similarly case-insensitive. For example, "D:" and "d:" refer to the same volume.

Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:

The following reserved characters:

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
```

Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File Streams.

Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

Use a period as a directory component in a path to represent the current directory, for example ".\temp.txt". For more information, see Paths.

Use two consecutive periods (..) as a directory component in a path to represent the parent of the current directory, for example "..\temp.txt". For more information, see Paths.

Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:

CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended. For more information, see Namespaces.

Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

Comment: I find it interesting that I couldn't create a folder with a name like 'con.anything' either.